Laravel Eloquent Union Query Returns "Cardinality Violation" Error Due to Different Number of Columns
I am using Laravel Eloquent to perform a union query on the same model but encountering a "Cardinality violation" error. The error message states:

The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns.

Here is my current code:
$subquery1 = TabellaMovimentiVista::selectRaw(
    'id AS subquery1_id,
    esercizio_id AS subquery1_esercizio_id,
    data AS subquery1_data,
    descrizione_mov AS subquery1_descrizione_mov,
    importo_totale AS subquery1_importo_totale,
    tipoArea AS subquery1_tipoArea,
    conto AS subquery1_conto,
    soggetto AS subquery1_soggetto,
    cassabancaposta AS subquery1_cassabancaposta,
    societa_id AS subquery1_societa_id,
    deleted_at AS subquery1_deleted_at'
)
->where('societa_id', Auth::user()->societa_id)
->where('esercizio_id', $this->esercizio['id'])
->whereNull('deleted_at');

$subquery2 = TabellaMovimentiVista::selectRaw(
    'id AS subquery2_id,
    esercizio_id AS subquery2_esercizio_id,
    data AS subquery2_data,
    descrizione_mov AS subquery2_descrizione_mov,
    importo_totale AS subquery2_importo_totale,
    tipoArea AS subquery2_tipoArea,
    conto AS subquery2_conto,
    soggetto AS subquery2_soggetto,
    cassabancaposta AS subquery2_cassabancaposta,
    societa_id AS subquery2_societa_id,
    deleted_at AS subquery2_deleted_at'
)
->where('societa_id', Auth::user()->societa_id)
->whereBetween('data', ['2024-01-01', '2024-12-31'])
->whereIn('conto', ['VERSAMENTO', 'PRELIEVO', 'GIROCONTO'])
->whereNull('deleted_at');

$results = $subquery1->union($subquery2)->get();

return $results;

The error is caused by Eloquent interpreting the two queries as having a different number of columns. Specifically, in the first select statement, it adds two columns:
`tabella_movimenti_view`.`data` AS `data`,
`tabella_movimenti_view`.`descrizione_mov` AS `descrizione_mov`,

The TabellaMovimentiVista Model right now looks like this:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TabellaMovimentiVista extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tabella_movimenti_view';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    use HasFactory;
}


I have tried troubleshooting the issue by checking the select statements generated by Eloquent and ensuring that they have the same number of columns. However, I am still unable to identify why Eloquent is adding additional columns in the first select statement.
I expected the union query to execute successfully without any errors, combining the results of the two subqueries into a single result set.
Any guidance on how to resolve this issue would be appreciated. Thank you.

Hello David, and welcome to SO. Please update your question with the code of your TabellaMovimentiVista model.
